# Separate Firebase Analytics from different Firebase apps

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I've a single Firebase project which includes multiple apps in multiple platforms (e.g. delivery company with different apps for customers and riders, some of them web apps, some of them iOS apps, some of them Android apps, etc).

Each of those apps registers Firebase Analytics events. It doesn't make sense to compare together those events, as they are sometimes related to very different use cases. Following with the example of the delivery company:

- Customer Android and iOS apps events should be considered together, as they are all the same
- Riders Android app should be apart, as they apply only to riders' actions
- Landing web page app events should also be separated, as while being triggered by the same audience (potential customers) as the customers, they don't have any thing to do with the customer app events.

The problem is all these events are presented together in Firebase Analytics dashboard and I can't find a way to segregate them by these "concerns". Ideally I would have three separated dashboards (customers, riders and landing page). I've tried creating different audiences, but the dimensions I found didn't made a fit. I can filter by platform, SO, etc, but nothing like "this user triggered these events in this Firebase app".

My bet right now is tagging all the events from the riders app with a default parameters like `{'app': 'riders-app'}`, but I guess there should be a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same (I'm also just starting to experiment with this), but you can define Audiences (in Google Analytics) for the different apps.

Go to Configure -> Audiences -> New audience -> Create custom

The filter is under "Platform / device" -> Stream

Note: you might need to play with the scoping parameter, not to have some crosstalk from users that use more apps - I'm not that far yet, so I don't know.